# To update image in ImageView which method is better setImageResource() or setImageDrawable()

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I am Android Newbie, while learning ImageView widgets I learned 2 possible methods to update image in ImageView.

This is the way the Instructor suggested:

```
onButtonClick(View view) {
    ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cn);
}
```

The other one is something I came up myself:

```
onButtonClick(View view) {
    ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    newDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cn);
    myImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
    myImageView.setImageDrawable(newDrawable);
}
```

I would like to understand a few things better:

- Which method is recommended in my case?
- What are pros/cons of using setImageResource() vs setImageDrawable()

Comment: I think is better to use setImageResource... I don´t remember exactly the case, but I worked in an app in production and some users saw the svg resources in black color (maybe API 21).   Finally, my cowerker fix the error using setImageResource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, setimageResource will be better because you just need to set the image.

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cn);
```

It will be worthwhile in case you need to do changes in drawable, like color filtering, resizing, etc.